# Why isn't Angular form reading property-binded input values?

Tags: angular, angular8, property-binding

I'm using property-binding to dynamically set the value on an input, it is being displayed properly, but when the form is submitted the value is undefined.

I'm using Angular 8.

```
<input type="number" [name]="x" [value]="expression" ngModel/>
```

Again, the value is *displaying* properly in the HTML. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this problem, bind to ngModel not value!

Answer (score 0):

You need two way binding for that.

`<input type="number" [name]="x" [(ngModel)]="expression"/>`

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding-

Comment: Thanks, one way binding works fine. Still not exactly sure why binding to value doesn't work but that's okay.